# Jest config transforms svg to `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jestjs

All my svg imports in Jest come out as undefined. Tried using `jest-svg-transformer` and `svg-jest` as `transform` and also as `moduleNameWrapper` in `jest.config.ts`, and also tried writing my own transformer as below but still no luck.

Here's my `jest.config.ts`:

```
import { JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  ...packageJson.jest,
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testTimeout: 20000,
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@src/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    uuid: require.resolve('uuid') // Force module uuid to resolve with the CJS entry point, because Jest does not support package.json.exports. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/451
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootdir>/src'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup-tests.ts', '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'],
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json'],
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': '@swc/jest',
    '^.+\\.ts?$': '@swc/jest',
    '^.+\\.m?jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/jest-svg-transformer.js'
  }
};

export default jestConfig;
```

File `jest-svg-transformer.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  process(src, filePath) {
    if (path.extname(filePath) !== '.svg') {
      return src;
    }

    const name = `svg-${path.basename(filePath, '.svg')}`
      .split(/\W+/)
      .map((x) => `${x.charAt(0).toUpperCase()}${x.slice(1)}`)
      .join('');

    return {
      code: `
const React = require('react');
function ${name}(props) {
  return React.createElement(
    'svg',
    Object.assign({}, props, {'data-file-name': ${name}.name})
  );
}
module.exports = ${name};
            `
    };
  }
};
```

[image]